# Convert a list into one row with dynamic column in MySQL

Tags: mysql-5.1

I have a list of row to be converted into a dynamic column that depends on the record in one particular column.

From this statement

```
FID  |Steps | Action 
---- |------|--------
1416 | 1    | Sit    
1416 | 2    | Run 
1416 | 3    | Jump 
1416 | 4    | Sit 
1416 | 5    | Run 
1416 | 6    | Skip 
1416 | 7    | Hit  
1416 | 8    | Run 
1432 | 1    | Hit
1432 | 2    | Guard
```

Into :

```
FID | 1   | 2     | 3    | 4    | 5   | 6    | 7   | 8    |
----|-----|-------|------|------|-----|------|-----|------|
1416| Sit | Run   | Jump | Sit  | Run | Skip | Hit | Run  |
1432| Hit | Guard | null | null | null| null | null| null |
```

How do I do this?
Please help. Thanks!